# FragmentTransaction after the Camera intent in ActivityOnRespond

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I'm using a Camera intent to take a picture. I'm using the Android guide and when the Intent starts it opens the Camera right away. However after completing it and going back to the application. I have a method which opens a new Fragment to edit this picture just taken.

However my old Fragments keeps showing, and I can't press any of the buttons.

This is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

fileUri = Uri.parse(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE).getAbsolutePath()); // create a file to save the image
MainActivity.imageUri = fileUri;
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name
intent.putExtra("uri", fileUri);

// start the image capture Intent
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Activity on result:

```
if(requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new FragmentEditPhoto())
                    .addToBackStack("EditPhoto").commit();
        }
```

My problem:

It won't show the fragment I want to see.

EditFragment Code :

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        _miContext = MIContext.getInstance();
        activity = getActivity();

    // Get tracker.
    Tracker t = ((MyApplication) activity.getApplication()).getTracker(MyApplication.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

    // Set screen name.
    t.setScreenName("EditPhoto");

    // Send a screen view.
    t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_photo, container, false);

    dw = (DrawView) v.findViewById(R.id.drawView1);

    //Intent ophalen en data eruit halen.
    //Filepath = String met filepath van de genomen of gekozen foto.
    //documentType = Declaraties of Inkooporder.
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    _imageUri = MainActivity.imageUri;
    doc = Settings.getCurrDoc();

    //FindViewsById's
    MainActivity.imageView = (OperationImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.Image);
    TextView button_back = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.button_back);
    ImageButton back = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton_back);
    ImageButton oke = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.button_oke);
    ImageButton snijden = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.button_snijden);
    ImageButton add = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.button_add);

    //Zorg dat buttons onderin over de imageview komen.
    oke.bringToFront();
    snijden.bringToFront();
    add.bringToFront();

    //Operations ophalen van ImageOperation.
    operations = Arrays.asList(ImageOperation.values());

    button_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainActivity.imageUri = null;

            activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

            activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new FragmentPickDocument())
                    .addToBackStack("PickDocument").commit();
        }
    });
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainActivity.imageUri = null;

            activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

            activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new FragmentPickDocument())
                    .addToBackStack("PickDocument").commit();
        }
    });
    snijden.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onImageOperationSelected(operations.get(4));
        }
    });
    oke.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (MainActivity.quad != null) {
                onImageOperationSelected(operations.get(3));
                MainActivity.quad = null;
            } else {
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ((BitmapDrawable) MainActivity.imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();


                //Add bundle with uri en byte[] "bitmap".
                FragmentManager manager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();

                manager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

                //activity.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

                //manager.beginTransaction()
                //     .remove(activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TakePhoto")).commit();


                FragmentCheck fragment = new FragmentCheck();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("uri", _imageUri.toString());
                bundle.putByteArray("bitmap", byteArray);
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);

                MainActivity.imageUri = null;

                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                        .addToBackStack("Check").commit();
            }
        }
    });
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onImageOperationSelected(operations.get(1));
        }
    });

    //ABBYY onCreate
    _dialog = createProgressDialog();
    final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    _miContext.setObservableData(new ObservableData(handler));
    try {
        loadImage();
    } catch (final IOException exception) {
        Log.e("IOException", "onCreate() failed", exception);
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
    _observer = createEngineObserver();
    _miContext.registerObserver(_observer);

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Post your FragmentEditPhoto code please.

Comment: I have added the requested code.